# 1d profile cutting optimization

Tags: c#, performance, vba, excel, combinatorics

I wanted to make a VBA that creates self-renewing combinations and I actually did it, but Excel was crashing when the combinations increased, unfortunately Excel does not work in multi-item lists. That's why I worked out the codes that create the combinations with C#. I am adding all my work, I think someone who understands software should develop this further. current operation. Cutting lengths in Excel are collected in a list. C# creates self-renewing combinations from numbers whose sum reaches the stock size. selects the largest one and prints it to Excel. The numbers entered in Excel are deleted from the first list and the process is repeated for the remaining cutting dyes. The process repeats until there is no cutting size left in the first list. Remember, I am not a software developer, these codes need to be improved.

Please test, we can do better together. Please review the shortcomings and errors of the codes and let me know the mistakes and shortcomings and teach me the correct one.

Result: It meets my needs.

https://github.com/OmurTokman/1d-profile-cutting-optimization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;    
namespace CSharpLibrary
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        // Method to call from VBA, taking a string of numbers separated by commas, and a target range
        public string CallCSharpDLL(string numbers, int targetMin, int targetMax, out long totalCombinationsTried)
        {
            // Convert the string from VBA into an array of integers
            int[] numbersArray = Array.ConvertAll(numbers.Split(','), int.Parse);

            // Find the maximum combination for each target within the given range
            List<int> maxCombination = new List<int>();
            totalCombinationsTried = 0;
            for (int target = targetMin; target <= targetMax; target++)
            {
                List<int> combination = FindMaxCombination(numbersArray, target, ref totalCombinationsTried);
                if (combination != null && combination.Sum() > maxCombination.Sum())
                {
                    maxCombination = combination;
                }
            }

            // Return the maximum combination found
            if (maxCombination.Count > 0)
            {
                return $"{string.Join(" + ", maxCombination)}";
              
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        // Method to find the maximum combination of numbers that sum up to the target
        private List<int> FindMaxCombination(int[] numbers, int target, ref long totalCombinationsTried)
        {
            List<int> maxCombination = new List<int>();
            int maxSum = int.MinValue;

            Array.Sort(numbers); // Sort the array in ascending order
            FindCombinationsHelper(numbers, target, 0, new List<int>(), ref maxCombination, ref maxSum, ref totalCombinationsTried);

            return maxCombination;
        }

        // Recursive helper method to find combinations
        private void FindCombinationsHelper(int[] numbers, int target, int index, List<int> current, ref List<int> maxCombination, ref int maxSum, ref long totalCombinationsTried)
        {
            totalCombinationsTried++;
            if (target == 0)
            {
                // Compare the current combination sum with the maximum sum found so far
                int sum = current.Sum();
                if (sum > maxSum)
                {
                    maxSum = sum;
                    maxCombination = new List<int>(current);
                }
                return;
            }

            for (int i = index; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > index && numbers[i] == numbers[i - 1])
                {
                    // Skip the same number at the same index to avoid repetition
                    continue;
                }

                if (target - numbers[i] < 0)
                {
                    // Break if exceeding the target
                    break;
                }

                current.Add(numbers[i]);
                FindCombinationsHelper(numbers, target - numbers[i], i + 1, current, ref maxCombination, ref maxSum, ref  totalCombinationsTried); // Recursive call
                current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1); // Backtracking
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I feel there has got to be a more efficient algorithm than trying every combination

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what method?